# Background image that I need to move an image view along a path in it

Tags: android

I have a bbackground image that shows a path with stations along this path. Now I have a sprite (basically an image of character)  that I was to move along this path.

Design wise, how do you approach this? Do I find the x, y coordinates of every step on the path and use that to animate the sprite moving theree?with different screen densities and size, will the above still valid (given that images are scaled down/up to match the size)?

Thank you so much

Comment: Use SurfaceView in android

Comment: You could write down the (x,y) of each station on your unscaled image and then use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` inside your methods to see what is the width and the height of your background on a particular device. You can then use this information to recalculate (x,y) for each station programmatically.

Comment: @Amy, why not normal framelayout activity with this background and views are being the sprites. It is not heavy animation.

Comment: @panonski...hmmm that's actually a great suggestion